# Dropping all tables in sqlite from php laravel before redoing entire migration

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

For testing purpose, I want to completely erase my sqlite database before replaying migrations.

So I have written this code:

```
DB::statement('PRAGMA writable_schema = 1');
DB::statement('delete from sqlite_master');
DB::statement('PRAGMA writable_schema = 0');

Artisan::call('migrate'); // one in two, I have the message : table "migrations" already exists
```

One in two (precisely), I have the message : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "migrations" already exists`

Comment: Have you tried the available commands, like `php artisan migrate:refresh`? That will drop all tables and re-run the migrations. Sidenote, I haven't worked with Sqlite, and if you try to run `php artisan migrate` when the `migrations` table exists, it _should_ trigger that error, so that seems really odd...

Comment: Thanks for `php artisan migrate:refres`, I didn't know. I guess you meant to write "this _shouldn't_ trigger this error", right?

Comment: Oh whoops... Yes, sorry; that shouldn't trigger that error.